# Issue with Parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, parsing, parsefloat

I have a function that adds cells together then populates the total into a textbox:

```
function UpdateTotal() {
    var total = parseFloat('0.0');

    $("#<%= gvParts.ClientID %>").find("tr").not(".tblResultsHeader").each(function () {
        var cellText = $(this).children("td").eq(4).html();
        var cellFloat = parseFloat(cellText)
        total += cellFloat;
    });

    $("#<%= txtAddParts.ClientID %>").val(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

But the problem is if the total is 1500.00 the `cellText` is reading it in as 1,500.00 I think this is causing a problem because `cellFloat` then equals to 1.00 and then it sets the textbox as 1.00 instead of 1500.00.

Comment: Can you post an example of the actual markup this js is working with? Not the aspx code, the actual generated html code of a couple of rows

Comment: provide the cellText console log thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the comma using regular expression like this:

```
parseFloat($("table").find("td").html().replace(/\,/g,''))
```